# Android ExpandableListView get first child of specefic Group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using android **ExpandableListView**  as following :

***Group Header Layout:***

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/traveller_data_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#0c333f"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

***Child Item Layout:***

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/traveller_data_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

// rest of my layout elments here

</LinearLayout>
```

I set my Own **BaseExpandableListAdapter** to bind groups and their children and it is binded correctly .

**MY Question here :**
I have the group position **(i)** and i want to get the first child of that group. Like that:

```
View childView =getChildView(groupPos,childPos)
```

In my case the childView  should be equal `traveller_data_content` layout.

How to implment `getChildView`

**HOW TO DO THAT??**

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do with that? You set the method up much like `getView()` of a `ListView`. That's where it shows each child in your adapter and you can set the child objects where you need to for each view.

Comment: my list view has groups and each groups has one child each child is about  4 editTexts and their parent layout is `traveller_data_content`   i want after click some button go to validate each data entered in every child's editTexts(Loop over each group child elments)

Comment: You should have a child object and be storing the values there. Then, when you click the button, you can just iterate over the child objects and check the data there.

Comment: good idea; it works fine .. thanks a lot :)